# Meteor.publish() throw an exception in defer callback

Tags: meteor

I found this error in the server console:

> Exception in defer callback: TypeError: undefined is not a function
>       at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1054:1
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Function.*.each.*.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:105:1)
>       at [object Object]._.extend._callStopCallbacks (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1053:1)
>       at [object Object]._.extend._deactivate (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1043:1)
>       at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:803:1
>       at Function.*.each.*.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:113:1)
>       at [object Object]._.extend._deactivateAllSubscriptions (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:802:1)
>       at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:444:1
>       at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)

And here the code I use:

```
/* Source: http://phucnguyen.info/blog/how-to-publish-to-a-client-only-collection-in-meteor/ */
var subs = {};
Meteor.publish(

// THROW AN 'EXCEPTION IN DERFER CALLBACK: ...'
  'helperPublication',  
  function () {
    var subscription = this;
    subs[subscription._session.id] = subscription;
    Datasets.find().map(function (dataset) {
      subscription.added(
        'subdatasets',
        dataset._id,
        {
          name: dataset.name,
          data: [],   // To avoid "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" error on load
          peaks: []   // Idem
        }
      )
    });
    subscription.onStop();
    subscription.ready()
});
```

You can find the whole app in the following meteorpad: http://meteorpad.com/pad/6NDneym2qEW7pF9JM/ClearChrom

Comment: I think there are multiple things you got wrong. What exactly are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: For performance matter, I use 2 separate databases. One is called Datasets and is shared by clients (restricted access) and server. The other one is a client only database: it stores clones of Datasets documents **BUT** keys 'data' are short subsets of data (load on demand).

With the code above, I would like to duplicate Datasets documents into the client side only database. And, optionally I want to do that for every client connected (but frankly, I don't really need _neither want_ to do that, but I did not know how to change that part of Phuc Nguyen's code...).

Does that make it clearer?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, So with that info; I think the best way to go about doing this is to have separate collection for that `data`. Because then you can easily change how much data should be displayed. The publication for that collection could look like this:

```
Meteor.publish('data', function publishData (limit) {
  return DataCollection.find({}, {
    fields: {
      name: 1,
      data: 1,
      peaks: 1
    },
    limit: limit
  })
});
```

Note that the callback of the publication takes an argument `limit`. You can now subscribe to it like this:

```
Meteor.subscribe('data', 3)
```

And whenever you need more data you can just:

```
Meteor.subscribe('data', 6)
```

So this solution is reactive and very clean (in my opinion at least).

I also checked your existing script:

```
var subs = {};

Meteor.publish(
  'helperPublication',
  function (limit) {
    var subscription = this;
    subs[subscription._session.id] = subscription;
    // I'd use forEach here, because you're not modifying the document
    Datasets.find().forEach(function (doc) {
      subscription.added(
        'subdatasets',
        doc._id,
        {
          name: doc.name,
          // Whith the slice function you can get a subset of the data array
          data: doc.data.slice(0, limit),
          peaks: doc.peaks
        }
      )
    });
    // Calling `subscription.onStop` without an argument doesn't do anything
    // Except maybe through an error
    subscription.onStop(function () {
      // clean the subscription from subs again
      delete subs[subscription._session.id];
    });
    // This shouldn't be necessary.
    // subscription.ready()
});
```

There are some issues with this still. For one thing I'd advise you to try avoiding meteor attributes with an underscore in front. **They might be removed or changed in future releases**.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with different approach. There is a Method inside Meteor docs.  (Check here in doc [Meteor.bindEnvironment](https://docs.meteor.com/api/environment#Meteor-bindEnvironment))

```
          const _this = this;

          Meteor.defer(Meteor.bindEnvironment(() => {

              // Your Code here

          }, () => {}, _this));
```

I think somehow it looses context with **this** inside Meteor.defer. And Above code provides that context. This way I resolved my issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).